# Uniqueness of the solution to a quadratic opt problem

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Consider a positive definite matrix $\boldsymbol H$, the known vectors ${\boldsymbol b}$  and ${\boldsymbol a}_i$. Now the minimization problem is casted with respect to the vector ${\boldsymbol x} $ and the scaler $y$ : 
\begin{equation}
     \begin{split}
     &\min_{\boldsymbol x, y} \, {\boldsymbol x}^\top {\boldsymbol H}  {\boldsymbol x} +  {\boldsymbol b}^\top {\boldsymbol x} + y \\
     & \text{subject to }    -{\boldsymbol a_i^\top \, x} + y \geq 0,  \; \text{ for }\forall i 
     \end{split}
\end{equation}
Although the Hessian of the objective function $\left(\begin{array}{cc}{\boldsymbol H} & {\boldsymbol 0}\\{\boldsymbol 0}^\top &0 \end{array}\right) $with respect to $[{\boldsymbol x}^\top,  y]^\top$ is semi-definite positive, I think the problem admits an unique solution, since we can replace $y$ in the objective by $\max_i {\boldsymbol a}_i^\top {\boldsymbol x}$, which is convex.

If this is correct,  could someone provides formal explanations using convex optimization theory to support this uniqueness? Thank you.